# How to cast loader output to a string

Tags: webpack

My webpack configuration looks like this:

```js
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    // ..
    module: {
        loaders: [
            // ..
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loaders: ['css', 'sass']
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

I want `require('./my-style.scss')` to return a string. However, now it is returning an `Array` object:

```
0: Array[3]
    0: 223
    1: "html,↵body,↵ol,↵ul,↵li,↵p { margin: 0; padding: 0; }↵"
    2: ""
    length: 3
i: (modules, mediaQuery) { .. }
length: 1
toString: toString()
```

I can cast the require statement to a string (`require('./my-style.scss').toString()`), though I'd webpack to do that for me.

How do I modify the loader definition to produce a string as the final output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have written a small loader that casts object to a string, [to-string](https://github.com/gajus/to-string).

It is a simple loader that executes content like a module and casts output to a string:

```js
/**
 * @see https://github.com/webpack/webpack/wiki/Loader-Specification
 */
module.exports = function (content) {
    return 'module.exports = ' + JSON.stringify(this.exec(content, this.resource).toString());
};
```