# How to define a loader inline?

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

The docs give an example of a loader [here](https://webpack.js.org/api/loaders/#synchronous-loaders), and the [old docs](https://webpack.github.io/docs/how-to-write-a-loader.html#examples) say I should be able to define an "identity loader" by returning what I'm given.

So in theory, adding `i => i` to my list of loaders (like below) shouldn't break anything.

```
module: {
    rules: [
        ...
        {
            test: /\.less$/,
            use: [ i => i, ...cssLoaders, lessLoader],
        },
    ]
},
```

But it causes this error:

```
/home/me/Projects/myproj/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.js:151
    var idxQuery = identifier.indexOf("?");

                         ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
```

Which is not in my code, but must be the result of me giving webpack something unexpected.

So what's the proper syntax for defining a loader (that does nothing) that I can use in the `use` array like that (without publishing a node module)?

Comment: hmm.. have you tried to pass an `function(i){return i;}` in instead of the arrow function? Thats just a guess, because arrow functions don't have a context.

Comment: @ShabbY Don't think that'll make a difference, but I'll try it. ... Nope, same error.

Comment: I received the same error even just using their first example here [[how to write a loader - examples](https://webpack.js.org/development/how-to-write-a-loader/#examples)] verbatim - both inline and from an external module didn't help. 
@mpen did you happen to figure out a solution? :)

Comment: @fierysunset No, I have not.

Answer (score 2):

### breakdown

*(pseudo code for understanding the concepts before reading the provided links to the full code)*

use `resolveLoader.alias` to "load" your loader

```
// in webpack config
resolveLoader: {
    alias: {
        'minimal-loader': require('path').resolve('./minimal-loader'),
    },
},
```

then you can access it via a string, in rules, as you were thinking, with an array of `use`

```
  module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /(.*)/,
            use: [{loader: 'minimal-loader'}],
        },
    ],
},
```

### resources

- https://webpack.js.org/development/how-to-write-a-loader/
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31474515/how-to-cast-loader-output-to-a-string

### code

*(working minimal examples made to show how to achieve this, as well as how to debug as you play around with it)*

- repo: https://github.com/aretecode/webpack-loader-guide/tree/master/examples/simple-string-loader
- gist: https://gist.github.com/aretecode/532539ba5caf2aad07fdbc9176ec1c0f

Comment: I can work with this, but it doesn't answer my question as stated. Is there no way to define the loader in the same file (webpack.config.js)? FYI, I'm pretty sure you could have used `require.resolve('./minimal-loader')` instead of using the `path` module.